# networkx: edge weight as a calculated value

Tags: python, graph, shortest-path, networkx

I want to implement a shortest path algorithm with NetworkX library. In my case, my weight function derives the value from other edge attributes. Because weight is a calculated value, I don't want to store it as an extra attribute to avoid the complication e.g. update the value when other attributes change. NetworkX's [algorithm API](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.single_source_dijkstra_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.single_source_dijkstra_path), however, seems requiring weight to be an edge data key.

So I was wondering if it's possible not to store the value? My ideal case would be to specify a custom weight function to the algorithm.

Comment: If you're going to use the NetworkX built-in method, I think you're stuck with storing the value and then updating it based on the values of other attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter does need to be a key in the edge attribute dictionary. So you need to set an edge attribute in the dictionary to use as a weight. You could assign those in a simple loop before computing the shortest path (and delete them later if you want).

Alternatively you could modify the Dijkstra algorithm code to compute your weight from the other edge attributes. Assuming you have a graph (not a multigraph) it is a one-line change. Put your weight formula in line 231
https://networkx.lanl.gov/trac/browser/networkx/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/weighted.py#L231

```
vw_dist = dist[v] + edgedata.get(weight,1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the weight value lazily, but present it as if it were an attribute, using properties. For example:

```
class Edge(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def get_z(self):
        return self.x + self.y

    z = property(get_z)


e = Edge(3,4)
print e.z
```

Here `e.z` appears to be an actual stored value, an attribute of the `Edge` object. But it's not - it's calculated on demand. You still have to write your update code, in the `get_z` method, but the benefit here is that you don't have to worry about updating a concrete value whenever the dependent properties change. Instead, you only calculate it when it is asked for.

It would be easy to extend this example to cache values, if you were concerned about many accesses of `z` causing needless potentially expensive calculations. The getter would check a look-up table before doing the calculation. This is just [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: In the case of NetworkX, it looks like the shortest-path function needs the parameter to be a key name of the dict associated with edges ([documentation](http://networkx.lanl.gov/tutorial/tutorial.html#adding-attributes-to-graphs-nodes-and-edges)). Though it's possible to use an arbitrary object as edges, I couldn't figure out how to make the shortest-path function use edge object property for weight values.